# Set background conditional on child class

Tags: css, less

I want to change the background of the parent (panel-heading) only when the child button has the class "collapsed" which occurs when it's clicked.  I can only use styles.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <button class="collapsed">...</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

LESS: (I found this but it's not working)

```
.panel-heading:has(button[class="collapsed"]) {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

OR

```
.panel-heading:has(button.collapsed) {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working, but since you are setting the background color to white, you can't tell the difference.

Try with different background color.

---

Check out below code by clicking on `Run code snippet` button.

```css
.panel-heading:has(button.collapsed) {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <button class="collapsed">...</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was just about to update my post as I noticed (I switched the default color and what I wanted it to change to and it worked) - you're pretty fast!  
Thanks!